# Is there a kinder way to say "I know"?

Tags: phrase-requests

"I know" is a ubiquitous statement commonly said in English. However, in some applications, it can be too harsh, or come off as rude.

For example, let's consider the following interaction. "Hey, Kyler, the Butterfly Festival is tomorrow." "I know, Finn." Phrases like "I understand" can be too formal and out of place, and "Thanks for reminding me" is situational and can only be used in instances similar to that.

I was wondering if there was a more polite, friendlier way to say the phrase whilst conveying the same meaning and can be used in any circumstance that "I know" can be used. Any thoughts?

Comment: I know! And I can’t wait! Are you going?

Comment: I don't see how there can be another phrase that fits _all_ circumstances. "I understand" could mean "I know what you must be feeling," - the other suggestions that people have made fit the meaning of "I already have that information".

Comment: Yeah. That’s right!

Comment: Intonation plays a role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always be more specific about *how* you know:

- "Oh, yes, it's on my calendar."
- "Thanks, I saw the article about the Festival in the *Times* this weekend."
- "You know, my little sister has been talking about nothing else all week."

And so forth.